# How to use redis store in express session using connect-redis?

Tags: session, express, express-session, session-store

I am trying to look for a tutorial that explains your how to setup user session in redis store using express session. I know how to set it up, but I could not find out how to access redis store and how to store and retrieve values from that redis store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to store and read values from the session (using the express-session module) and not use redis directly. For this you'll want to use the `req.session` object in a request.

Checkout the functions here in the documentation - https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession

If you're trying to store some values directly into redis (perhaps using redis for multiple things) then checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis

Comment: I am using connect-redis for my session management and passing a redis store in express session. The problem is that every time I set the value of user in /auth/facebook/callback route of passport js (req.session.key=req.user). This key is undefined in my /session_accessor route.  How can I get the session value in another route? I assume that I am not setting the value correctly

Comment: If you're using passportjs you shouldn't need to interact with redis at all on your own. You simply setup the middleware as shown in the docs here http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure and passport will handle the session for you, then you just need to go back and plug in redis to express-session before handing it to passport.

req.session will be populated and read from using the serialize and deserialize functions. This again removes the need to interact with req.session yourself.